# Gazebo - How to manually input coordinates of objects

Tags: gazebo-2.2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

Im using gazebo 2.2 (ubuntu 14 trustly with ROS indigo). I created my world with a TurtleBot robot inside for simulation purposes.

Now what I'm looking for is a way to manually input initial coordinates of objects. I want to select an object, for example said Turtlebot (mobile_base) and then place it exactly at X = 1.5, Y = 1.5, Z = 0 and then give it rotation yaw = -1

How do i do it?

When i select world object mobile_base it has "pose" property that can be edited but i cant see a way to save these new values, each time i click outisde of the world tab, they reset to previous values.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17980/gazebo---how-to-manually-input-coordinates-of-objects/) by [Multiplexer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4192/multiplexer/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It sounds like you're just starting, so I'd recommend you step back a bit and reinstall everything to run ROS Kinetic with Gazebo 7, since Gazebo 2 hasn't been supported for a long time.

After that, I recommend you go through Gazebo + ROS tutorials before diving into the code: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=connect_ros

#### Update

Is this what you're trying to do? This is Gazebo 7.8.1:

[image: image description]

Note that Gazebo 2 being outdated is only one of the possible reasons why it isn't working for you. You could have a joint pulling the robot back to the original place, or some ROS node publishing poses...

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Multiplexer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4192/multiplexer/) on 2017-12-01**:
So entering object coordinates by hand *while designing world* is not supported in gazebo 2.2?

Is it a confirmed feature in Gazebo 7?

I dont want to change my whole configuration just to find out that its not possible either in Gazebo 7.

Thank you for reply.

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2017-12-01**:
I updated the answer to address this comment. I'm not saying it isn't possible on Gazebo 2, just that I wouldn't be surprised if it weren't working there.

**Comment by [Multiplexer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4192/multiplexer/) on 2017-12-04**:
thanks you thats what i was looking for, im installing Gazebo 7 with kinetic to see if it works